# Encoding Video With Variable Framerate

Tags: encoding, ffmpeg, video-streaming, precision, video-processing

I have a list of timestamped images in a folder. All of the images are named %12d_us.jpeg (i.e.000000020038_us.jpeg , etc. etc.). These images were recorded at a variable framerate so while one video may have been captured at 40 fps for others the fps may have dipped to 30 or even 20 fps. However I do have the time stamp for each of these images encoded in their names. Is there a way to encode these images such that they resemble the original video stream from which they were captured (that is at a dynamic framerate).

If anyone can be of assistance with this I would greatly appreciate it. I should add that I'm running windows so I can't use the glob pattern because it's not part of my operating system's POSIX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use FFmpeg's concat feature: http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#concat-1

ffmpeg -i duration.txt -c:a copy -vf fps=30 output.mp4

You have to generate duration.txt based on your file names - like:

```
ffconcat version 1.0
file 000000020038_us.jpeg
duration 2
file 000000050039_us.jpeg
duration 5
file 000000010040_us.jpeg
duration 1
```

Comment: This worked perfectly. I was able to get it to accept durations that were fractional as well. I used decimals with 6 places for duration and it worked.

Comment: What if the durations are fractional?

Comment: Can this be done with stdin, without writing the images to disk?

Comment: @B''HBi'ezras--BoruchHashem you can use '-use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1'. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60977555/adding-current-time-as-timestamp-in-h-264-raw-stream-with-few-frames