# Adding current time as timestamp in H.264 raw stream with few frames

Tags: ffmpeg, timestamp, video-streaming, h.264, video-capture

I have a program that spits out an H.264 raw stream (namely, `screenrecord` on Android). I'm using [FFmpeg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FFmpeg) to add a PTS (presentation time stamp) on the frames as follows:

```
$ my-program | ffmpeg -i - -filter:v setpts='(RTCTIME - RTCSTART) / (TB * 1000000)' out.mp4
```

This filter computes the current time, and puts it as the PTS.

The trouble is that `my-program` does not produce any output if there isn't any change in the video. Since FFmpeg seems to wait for a bunch of frames before putting them through the `setpts` filter, the computed PTS won't be correct. In particular, the last frame of a sequence will be timestamped when the next sequence starts.

Is there a way (with FFmpeg or otherwise) to add the current time as PTS to H.264 raw frames, where "current time" is when *receiving* the frame, rather than outputting it?

*Note:* The problem is *not* from buffering from the pipe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign the timestamps earlier, letting setpts simply normalize it to start from 0.

```
 my-program | ffmpeg -use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1 -i - -filter:v setpts='PTS-STARTPTS' out.mp4
```

`-use_wallclock_as_timestamps` is assigned by the libavformat framework when receiving the packet.

Comment: Amazing, thanks a lot Gyan, that works beautifully!  The termux version of ffmpeg on Android seems to be too slow to do that on the fly, so I'm piping the stream over the network.  Any chance that doing a small program based on https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/remuxing_8c_source.html would be faster for that purpose?  My goal is to encapsulate in MKV, or any format that would still be readable if my Android crashes during recording.  Sorry for the side question!  And thanks again for your help!

Comment: It's the decoding and (especially) re-encoding which is slow, not the setpts filtering per se. Yes, pure remuxing should be much faster, But you'll have to normalize the PTS yourself - that's simply removing the offset of the first packet.

Comment: Oh, I see, then simply using `ffmpeg -use_wallclock_as_timestamps 1 -i - -c:v copy out.mkv` would do most of the job, and my Android tablet can actually do this fast enough.  I can then renormalize on my computer (although the file seems to play fine without renormalization).  If my tablet crashes during recording, the MKV file would still be readable with the correct timestamps, so I can salvage that.  Perfect!  Thanks so much Gyan, keep up the great work!